# How to do a switch statement using a url and Contains()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, switch-statement

I have some urls that look like this: `/Collection/Summary?ViewBy=AZ`

I'm trying to implement a switch statement so that if the url contains X, then Y will happen.

This was working when it was just an if/else, but I'm not sure how it would work with the switch expression, especially the `Contains` part.

Here's the code snippet:

```
@{ 
    switch(Request.RawUrl.Contains)
    {
        case "Summary":
        case "Detail":
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/global");
            break;
        default:
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/site");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your search terms in a list or an array, we can use the `FirstOrDefault` extension method to get the first item in the list that the raw url contains, and you can write code similar to what you seem to be wanting:

```
var keywords = new[] {"Summary", "Detail"};

switch(keywords.FirstOrDefault(Request.RawUrl.Contains))
{
    case "Summary":
    case "Detail":
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/global");
        break;
    default:
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/site");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` is a function not a property or variable to match against. Use `ToString` or `Substring` instead.

Another way, try:
     `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`